# Composer with --no-dev only config

Tags: composer-php, autoloader

The composer documentation says about optimizations that "You should not enable any of these optimizations in development as they all will cause various problems when adding/removing classes. The performance gains are not worth the trouble in a development setting." (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md)

In composer.json, is there any way to configure a "config" section that applies to `--no-dev` installs or updates only?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way, sadly. You will need to remember to setup your deployment to run Composer on your production and development machines with or without the documented flags, respectivelly.

That being said, in production, if you run PHP 7, it is in 99% of the cases enough to run Composer with `composer install --no-dev -o` (method 1), since: a) Method 2A is not 100% reliable, b) Method 2B (APCu cache) is superfluous since method 1 is cached in opcache.

Comment: Why do you think that method 2A is not reliable? Method 2B is not superfluous, the second level of optimizations is for speedup misses (may be important if you have multiple autoloaders).

Comment: For 2A, as per docs, it does not autoload classes generated at runtime, which personally I had issues with on some projects. Since I cannot know the scope of the projects of the question author, it was worthwhile to metion. As for 2B, I might've misunderstood the docs, so thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Docker on production. The Jenkins is building the Docker images, while doing it installs the composer packages with that optimisations. But on the dev env we just do `install` with no args and it works super fine.